# Read columns headers from txt file and create output csv by copying columns from other csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a .txt file that consists of column names that I need to extract from a csv file and create a new filtered csv file with only the columns mentioned in the .txt file. I tried to google this.. but couldn't find anything.. please help...
for e.g.
`columns.txt` file is as below

```
Reason_code_01
Reason_code_03 
Application_id
```

The csv file consists of the columns in `columns.txt` file and many more and looks like below :

```
Reason_code_01,Reason_code_02,Reason_code_03,Reason_code_04 and so on.......................... 
AA,BB,CC,DD, and so on..........
A1,BB,1C,DD, and so on..........
AA,BB,CC,D1, and so on..........
```

```
           col_sel = open("columns.txt", "r")
           Lines = col_sel.readlines() 
           df_pre = pd.read_csv("input.zip")
           df_col_pre = pd.DataFrame()
           for line in Lines :                
               if line.strip() != "" : 
                   df_col_pre[line.strip()].append(df_pre[line.strip()])
           df_col_pre.to_csv('SerBase_sel.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

getting below error :

```
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1215, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20359)

KeyError: 'Reason_code_01'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Turns out silly mistake..

```
        col_sel = open("columns.txt", "r")
        Lines = col_sel.readlines() 
        df_pre = pd.read_csv("Input.zip")
        count = 0 
        df_col_pre = pd.DataFrame()
        for line in Lines :                
            if line.strip() != "" : 
                df_col_pre[line.strip()] = (df_pre[line.strip()])
```